# Get Android WebView content width with vertical scrolling after page loaded

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to get Android WebView content width after the webpage loaded with vertical scroll using java?

Comment: What do you mean by content width? The width of the webview?

Comment: I mean I want to know showing html page height and width, not the webview height/width. Thanks

Comment: Do you own the page you want to load in the webview? i.e can you modify the page?

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview/

Comment: Yes I loaded my html file from asset. Thanks for the above link.

Answer (score 7):

In case you have the option to extend the used WebView you can also try the output of the protected Method computeHorizontalScrollRange().

Update: I forgot to mention that this only works properly if the content is bigger than the webview.

```
class YourCustomWebView extends WebView {
    public YourCustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public int getContentWidth()
    {
        return this.computeHorizontalScrollRange();
    }
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView page, String url) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"ContentWidth: " + ((YourCustomWebView) page).getContentWidth());
}
```

Comment: computeHorizontalScrollRange() is always returning zero for me. Any other workaround?

Answer (score 4):

You need the width and height of the WebView CONTENTS, after you loaded your HTML.
YES you do, but there is no getContentWidth method (only a view port value),
AND the getContentHeight() is inaccurate !

Answer: sub-class WebView:

```
/*
  Jon Goodwin
*/
package com.example.html2pdf;//your package

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.webkit.WebView;

class CustomWebView extends WebView
{
    public int rawContentWidth   = 0;                         //unneeded
    public int rawContentHeight  = 0;                         //unneeded
    Context    mContext          = null;                      //unneeded

    public CustomWebView(Context context)                     //unused constructor
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = this.getContext();
    }   

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) //inflate constructor
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getContentWidth()
    {
        int ret = super.computeHorizontalScrollRange();//working after load of page
        rawContentWidth = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    public int getContentHeight()
    {
        int ret = super.computeVerticalScrollRange(); //working after load of page
        rawContentHeight = ret;
        return ret;
    }
//=========
}//class
//=========
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check, http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview/

There is method `webview.getContentHeight();` for getting the content height. There is no method to get the content width. You can do that using javascript, and getting it from javascript using JavaScriptInterface. Since you are loading from assets folder, you can easily add the javascript function and make a JavascriptInterface.

Comment: In case anyone wants to see what was in this dead link: http://web.archive.org/web/20140218103526/http://android.pimmos.com/2011/03/24/how-to-retrieve-the-contentwidth-of-a-webview